# Safari favourites shortcut not working until 15-20 seconds after app opening

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

Pressing `option`+`command`+`1-9` in safari opens the corresponding favourite from your bookmarks:

[image: Keyboard shortcuts for favourites]

However this shortcut only starts working 15-20 seconds after safari is opened. This is very inconvenient, as this is the time when you're most likely to want to use the shortcut.

In **Bookmarks**, the **☆ Favourites** tab doesn't appear immediately after opening, which I assume has something to do with the shortcut not working:

[image: Bookmarks tab upon opening safari]

Always keeping safari running ensures that the shortcut works, however I would prefer if there was a way to always have it work upon opening.

Comment: Interesting issue - personally I don't think I've ever had the Mac running without Safari running too. I get a similar annoyance as the Mac starts up, on the very few occasions I ever reboot it, in that it takes about 30s before all my background/menu bar tasks start up. tbh, it wouldn't hurt to always have Safari running, even if all windows are closed. On its own it doesn't have much of a footprint.